# Increase Font size in Thunderbird

Tags: imac, high-sierra

I have recently purchased an iMac to replace my 13" MacBook Pro and am gradually setting it up.

My eyesight is fading, so I intend to use the bigger screen to improve readability.

One application I am having problems with is `Thunderbird`. The list of messages in my Inbox remains stubbornly small.

I have tried changing Font size in Preferences/Display to no avail.

Comment: this is still an issue in Thunderbird 78.10 on Macos 10.14.6. Changing font in the Language & Appearance settings makes no change on the display of a message content, strangely only seems to change the font size of the '1 more' button to display more emails addresses who are CCed...

Answer (score 1):

Theme Font & Size Changer sometimes disappear from Thunderbird. You simply cannot see the button to the options for this add-on. In order to make Theme Font & Size Changer add-on working for Thunderbird, you need to change the xpi-file (which is basically a zip file) before you import the add-on to Thunderbird.

You need to change the `Bootstrap.js` file inside the `.xpi` file. `Bootstrap.js` is a large file, and you have to comment out a line, rezip the files, and rename the extension from zip to xpi and reinstall the module.

[Source](http://zoomtek.dk/ressourcer-blog)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to install the ["Theme Font & Size Changer for ThunderBird"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/theme-font-size-changer-for-tb/?src=search) (in Tools|Add-Ons|Get Add Ons search for "font size") that has a "zoom" feature that impacts the whole ThunderBird UI

Answer (score 0):

So you tried changing it this way?

> Change the Default Mozilla Thunderbird Message Font To set your own
>   default font for composing new messages in Mozilla Thunderbird:
>
> - Make sure each account is [set to composing with HTML formatting](https://www.lifewire.com/compose-html-messages-thunderbird-1173108).
> - Select Tools | Options (or Thunderbird | Preferences... on a Mac) from the menu in Mozilla Thunderbird.
> - Go to the Composition category.
> - Make sure the General tab is selected.
> - Choose the desired font, font size, and colors under HTML.
> - Click Send Options....
> - Make sure either Ask me what to do, Send the message in HTML anyway    or Send the message in both plain text and HTML is selected under
>     When sending messages in HTML [...].
> - Click OK.
> - Close the configuration dialog.

via [Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/change-default-font-thunderbird-1173143)

Comment: No! I am trying to change the font in Inbox